# How to auto detect changes on a page and refresh content with AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've got a simple help desk type system using WordPress posts. If you refresh the page, it queries the database and displays any new replies.

At the moment I am refreshing the page every couple of minutes to grab fresh replies, but this isn't the best option because if someone is writing a reply, it could be lost when the page reloads.

I'd like the page to be able to auto-detect any new replies/messages coming in and refresh the page automatically with AJAX. Is there a script I can find somewhere to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Is there a script I can find somewhere to achieve this?` - unlikely, who's going to write a script that suits your exact data and page content? You'll have to write the code yourself

Comment: have you looked at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload ?

Comment: You can use a `setInterval()` to check at regular intervals, which isn't exactly the same as live-detecting but may be much easier to accomplish.

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you so much for you valuable input. Haven't you heard of composer or NPM? Aren't these essentially just scripts that other people have written which you can incorporate into your own apps? I didn't realize it was a crime to save time & use something prewritten.

Comment: Thanks @jmp I'll look into the docs & perhaps seek help when I have some code written :)

Comment: Those libraries will still need you to write your own code

Answer (score 0):

To recap from the comments, these web apis will help accomplish the goal but overall the question is not answerable given the current information.

> I'd like the page to be able to auto-detect any new replies/messages coming in

This can be accomplished, in theory, using the [MutationObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) though I don't know this to be available in all browsers.

> refresh the page automatically with AJAX.

AJAX is not needed to refresh the page. The [Location.reload() web api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) can refresh the page and may meet the use case in theory.

Additionally, I can infer that it is not the page but just a div on the page that needs to be appended with the update from a REST API. This can be done in JavaScript though more specific implementation is dependent on more details.

Comment: Thanks for your attempt at answering my unanswerable question :P There's some useful information here that I will looker into. 

Just to add to my question. I've seen help desks that update without the page refreshing, similar too a live chat, except it's not technically a live chat.  Which way would you recommend I go to achieve something similar?